# why function 1 is not calling fun2

Tags: python-3.x

why function is not working?

```
def fun2(a,b):
    a.sort(key = lambda item: ([str,int].index(type(item)), item))
    print(a[b-1],a[b-2])

def filter(x,y):
    list2=[]
    q=200
    while x!=200:
        if  y[x]%1 ==0 :
            list2.append(y[x])
            x=x+1
    fun2(list2,q)
list1=[]
a=0
b=0
c=0.5
d=65
z=0
while a!=100:
    list1.append(a)
    a=a+1
while b!=50:
    list1.append(c)
    b=b+1
    c=c+0.43
while d!=115:
    list1.append(chr(d))
    d=d+1
q=len(list1)
print(list1)
print(filter(z,list1))
```

why filter is not calling function 2?
why is the mistake i am making here ?
i want to print 2 greatest integer from the list2

Comment: Where is `function1`? You mean `filter`? Also doing some research on `for` statements with `range` and list comprehension will probably be pretty useful for you.

Comment: We can't see any `function 1`, please check your code if you are talking about `filter` or something else?

Comment: yea by function 1 i meant filter

Comment: It looks like it is called. What is the output you expect?

Comment: 98 and 99 fun2 is suppose to get two biggest numbers from the list2

Comment: You have an infinite loop in `filter`. That being said if you give a desired input and desired output I can give you code that is a lot cleaner...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got an infinite loop here:

```
while x != 200:
    if  y[x]%1 == 0 :
        list2.append(y[x])
        x = x + 1
```

As soon as `y[x]` is not an integer, the condition is not True, and `x` is no more incremented.

You probably wanted to do:

```
while x <= 200:
    if y[x] == int(y[x]):
        list2.append(y[x])
    x += 1
```

**Update**: Oh, and I see you also got non-numeric items in your list...
Plus, you should not use a `while` loop to iterate over a list. Here is a better approach

```
for item in y:
    try:
        if item == int(item):
            list2.append(item)
    except ValueError:
        pass
```

Comment: Please fix the operator spacing.

Comment: `x=x+1` should be `x = x + 1` or just `x += 1`.  You probably should swap our the `while` loop with a `for` loop as well since it looks like the OP doesn't know what a `for` loop is.

Comment: Yeah, I was just thinking about this while loop (but that's the entire code that could be rewritten...)

Comment: code not still working giving this error"Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Usman\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\ddasf.py", line 32, in <module>
    print(filter(z,list1))
  File "C:\Users\Usman\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\ddasf.py", line 9, in filter
    if y[x] == int(y[x]):
IndexError: list index out of range"

Comment: Because x becomes greater than the length of the list you are interating on. See my update

Comment: Glad to know, consider marking the question as solved if this helped you